Angular Unit Tests Fail with NullInjectorError: No Provider for Store and HttpClient
I have app.module.ts
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { FontAwesomeModule } from "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome";
import { SharedModule } from "@shared/shared.module";
import { AppComponent } from "@app/app.component";
import { CourseInfoComponent } from "@features/course-info/course-info.component";
import { NotAuthorizedGuard } from "@app/auth/guards/not-authorized.guard";
import { AuthorizedGuard } from "@app/auth/guards/authorized.guard";
import { CoursesStoreService } from "@app/services/courses-store.service";
import { CoursesService } from "@app/services/courses.service";
import { CoursesComponent } from "./features/courses/courses.component";
import { CoursesListComponent } from "./features/courses/courses-list/courses-list.component";
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import { WindowRefService } from "./shared/provides/window.provider";
import { TokenInterceptor } from "./auth/interceptors/token.interceptor";
import { StoreModule } from "@ngrx/store";
import { EffectsModule } from "@ngrx/effects";
import { effects, reducers } from "./store/courses";
import { CoursesFacade } from "./store/courses/courses.facade";
import { CoursesEffects } from "./store/courses/courses.effects";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CourseInfoComponent,
    CoursesComponent,
    CoursesListComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    SharedModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers),
    EffectsModule.forRoot(effects),
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthorizedGuard,
    NotAuthorizedGuard,
    CoursesService,
    CoursesStoreService,
    WindowRefService,
    HttpClientModule,
    CoursesFacade,
    CoursesEffects,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: TokenInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}

and shared module
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { FontAwesomeModule } from "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome";
import { ModalComponent } from "./components/modal/modal.component";
import {
  HeaderComponent,
  ButtonComponent,
  InfoComponent,
  SearchComponent,
  CourseCardComponent,
  LoginFormComponent,
  RegistrationFormComponent,
  CourseFormComponent,
} from "./components";
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { DurationPipe } from "./pipes/duration.pipe";
import { CustomDatePipe } from "./pipes/custom-date.pipe";
import { EmailValidatorDirective } from "@shared/directives/email.directive";

const components = [
  HeaderComponent,
  ButtonComponent,
  InfoComponent,
  SearchComponent,
  ModalComponent,
  CourseCardComponent,
  LoginFormComponent,
  RegistrationFormComponent,
  CourseFormComponent,
  DurationPipe,
  CustomDatePipe,
  EmailValidatorDirective,
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [components],
  imports: [CommonModule, FontAwesomeModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  exports: [components],
})
export class SharedModule {}

The app is working fine, but when i run the tests, i got 0 score and error messages:
Details:NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[CoursesFacade -> Store -> Store]: NullInjectorError: No provider for Store! at NullInjector.get (/autocode/5ce10ff9-8a91-4e7a-bec5-464985f1b430/repository/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:7493:27) at R3Injector.get (/autocode/5ce10ff9-8a91-4e7a-bec5-

and
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[CoursesService -> HttpClient -> HttpClient]: NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient! at NullInjector.get (/autocode/5ce10ff9-8a91-4e7a-bec5-464985f1b430/repository/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:7493:27) at

Since this is autocode check, i dont have access to the code of these test. I cant change the tests. But i dont really understand, where do these errors come from and how to fix it, since the app is working fine.

 I cant change the tests. & how to fix it don't go along together very well. Without  any relevant code it would be just guessing.

This is most likely because the dependencies Store and HttpClient are not being provided in the context of the test files. In Angular unit tests you need to configure and provide any services or dependencies that your components or services rely on even if they are configured correctly in your main application module which is your app module
For example in your test file you can include the imports and configuration
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { reducers } from 'path/to/your/reducers';
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';

describe('YourComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        StoreModule.forRoot(reducers), // or specify particular modules as needed
        EffectsModule.forRoot([]), // add specific effects if needed
      ],
      declarations: [YourComponent],
      providers: [
        // Aay other services you may need to mock for your component
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  // you can add your tests here
});


It is clearly written in the question that the tests cannot be changed
